# Can't install private package globally

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just developed a custom package that I'm planning to drop to some customers.
I built the package using `python setup.py sdist` and these are contents of my `setup.py` file:

```py
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from distutils.util import convert_path

main_ns = {}
ver_path = convert_path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/version.py')

try:
    with open(ver_path) as ver_file:
        exec (ver_file.read(), main_ns)
except IOError:
    main_ns['__version__'] = '0.0.0'

setup(name='foobbar',
      version=main_ns['__version__'],
      description='SomeDescription',
      license='GPL',
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=True,
      install_requires=[
          'packaging',
          'Pillow',
          'requests',
          'pyserial'
      ],
      extras_require={
            'picamera': ['picamera']
      }
      )
```

Everything is built correctly. The problem happens when I try to install it. I un-tar everything, get inside the package folder and run `python setup.py install --user`. Looking at the output, everything seems fine. If I start a python console, I can import the module **BUT** if I change directory, I get an import error.

What's going on?
This is my first time creating a package, so most likely I'm doing something wrong.

I checked my local directory and it seems that the module is there:

```sh
$ ll .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
... snip ...
-rw-rw-r--  1 tampe125 tampe125  32K gen 19 23:09 foobar-0.0.2-py2.7.egg
```

I checked the `sys.path` property and my local directory is there:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/tampe125/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-3.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-5.4.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/tampe125/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging-18.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/tampe125/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-2.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/tampe125/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar-0.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera-1.13-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyYAML-4.2b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iso8601-0.1.12-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/future-0.17.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

What am I missing?
P.s. Obviously the name of the module is NOT `foobar`, I just redacted it.